# Authenticate google apps user account credentials

Tags: c#, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk, google-client-login

I am working with google admin .net apis .I want to authenticate a user in my application without redirecting to google's own authentication page.I have drilled it down on internet but nothing found any thing helpful regarding this.kindly suggest me a way to do this.if there is any third party authentication system for this please tell me about it.
Thanks in advance folks.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google's Admin SDK, it uses OAuth2.0 for authentication and authorization.